# How to put that n cells ( TextViews ) inside <LinearLayout> have a same width ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How to put that n cells ( TextViews ) inside  have a same width ? I can from code get size of screen and then calculate, but I wonder is there any way to do that from xml ? I cannot hardcode width.

Answer (score 2):

from: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/

Never forget the power of:

```
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
```

that's really easy to do:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can change your android:layout_weight to wathever you want and don't forget to set android:layout_height="0dip"(or width)

Answer (score 0):

Have your TextViews have a width of 0px but all have the same weight - this should cause them all to have the same width.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `android:layout_weight="1"` and give `android:layout_width="0dip"` in every TextView you want.

For example:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```